# JSONObject getting truncated in Android

Tags: android, json, salesforce

My application is trying to connect to the Salesforce API and pulldown all the Contacts existing in it. The response json object has a key called "totalSize" which says 33231 records. When i try to access the records as JSONArray, my JSONArray contains only 2000 records. Somewhere the jsonobject might be getting truncated. Can you please help. Following is my code.

```
JSONObject asJSONObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(result));
int totalRecordsSize = Integer.parseInt(asJSONObject.getString("totalSize"));
System.out.println("JSON_RESULT_SIZE : "+totalRecordsSize);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)asJSONObject.get("records");
int count = array.length();
System.out.println("JSON_ARRAY_SIZE : "+count);
```

Thanks

Comment: There is a good chance that the Json object is truncated by the server and not by Android. Hence you might want to include in your question some details about your call to the server; what type of API do you use (REST, SOAP, Bulk), which call did you try to do. And in order to get a clear cut if the problem is in the server or Android try to sniff your network communication with tools like wireshark and check your actual response from the server. Does it include 33231 records or only 2000. After publishing your result it will help others to help you, you might even find the solution yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The salesforce server sends results in 2000 row chunks, part of the response structure is a `nextRecordsUrl` that contains the URL to the next page of results, you need to do a GET on that to get the next set of records and so on until you've fetched your entire result set.

Answer (score 0):

Usually such issues occurs when your server is configured (perhaps by default) to respond limited amount of data in response to a web call. For example, if you are using **ASP.NET** webservice, then the default Json response length is limited to *100kb*. However, you may overwrite this limit by simply increasing the response length in your web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5242880"/>  <!-- 5MB -->
      </webServices>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

With above config, my json response would go up to 5MB, but make sure you also increase HTTP connection time-out values when dealing with huge amount of data. For example:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 60000);  //1 minute
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 60000);          //1 minute
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```